# Trigger animation on element click in pure CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions

Let's say I have a simple element:

```
<a href="#" id="btn" onclick="return false">Click</a>
```

Now I can change the look of this element on click via `:active`:

```
#btn:active {
    background: red;
}
```

What I'd like however is that the element will stay red for about a second after I clicked it without altering the HTML (so no checkbox hack) or javascript. Is there a smart trick that can be abused for this?

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/s3G7p/)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Answering my own question. By abusing the `:not` pseudo class we can trigger an animation after a onclick happened:

```
#btn:not(:active) {
    /* now keep red background for 1s */
    transition: background-color 1000ms step-end;
}

#btn:active {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: I found this can be made a lot more useful with a tiny bit of JS, rather than the not(:active) trick, adding a "fly" class to get something to slide off a page :-) http://jsfiddle.net/28Qfx/

Comment: Yeah sure, but the question was how to do this in pure CSS.

Comment: Yeah, sorry Jan just wanted to share :-o

Comment: Very useful in cases you are assinged the role of the 'dump'-designer and are not allowed to touch the 'cool' guys javascript, but have to trigger an animation on button-click. Helped me out quite a bit for animating a datepicker-component without touching the implementation. Otherwise i would avoid selectors like this like the devil, but if you have to hack around it `.uib-daypicker thead:not(:active) + tbody .btn { animation: FadeOutIn 1s linear; }` Thanks a lot

Comment: This has the only downfall of the effect happening when the element is first spawned.. Any ideas how to work around?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `CSS3 animations` and trigger with the `:focus` & `:active`...
Now, you can activate the effect with just pressing the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key...

But if you need to activate it with a <kbd>mouse click</kbd>.... and in a `a tag` you need to set the focus to the object, so some `javascript` is required. *(inline in this case)*

If you can use another object, let say an `input type="text"` then the `focus` it's automaticly set when you do the `click`, but in this case the `focus` action it's given by the browser.

So, the **inline JS required is:**

```
<a href="#" id="btn" onclick="this.focus();return false">Click</a>
```

#### And the CSS3 code

```
#btn {
    background: yellow;
}

#btn:focus, #btn:active {
    -webkit-animation: btn-color 1s forwards linear;
    -moz-animation: btn-color 1s forwards linear;
    -ms-animation: btn-color 1s forwards linear;
    -o-animation: btn-color 1s forwards linear;
    animation: btn-color 1s forwards linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes btn-color { 0% { background: red; } 99% { background: red; } 100% { background: yellow; } }
@-moz-keyframes btn-color { 0% { background: red; } 99% { background: red; } 100% { background: yellow; } }
@-ms-keyframes btn-color { 0% { background: red; } 99% { background: red; } 100% { background: yellow; } }
@-o-keyframes btn-color { 0% { background: red; } 99% { background: red; } 100% { background: yellow; } }
@keyframes btn-color { 0% { background: red; } 99% { background: red; } 100% { background: yellow; } }
```

#### See a working fiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/s3G7p/1/

Comment: Yes, but this requires altering the javascript in the page to call `this.focus()` which cannot be done.

Comment: And what about altering the `JS function` instead?... see this: http://jsfiddle.net/s3G7p/2/ (like yours but with `this.focus();` before the `return false;`)

Comment: The thing is that I dont have control over user code, I can only alter the CSS. The return false is already there :-)

Comment: I understand ... and if you do not mind asking, what method you use to alter the css file?

Comment: The CSS file is part of the shared library of UX Building Blocks we have in Firefox OS. Other apps consume this library, so I can't change all of them.

Comment: Mmm.. difficult then. One more Q. that file/style, how is included in the doc.? Inline... `<style>...</style>` or as an external reference? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="">`

Comment: Mmm... I think we can't then... If we can't associatte to that `a` an `event`, I think it will be impossible to attach an animation to it. Only with `states` and in a `a tag`... don't know. BTW, the question about how you include the css, was because I was thinking in use a trick to inject `js` from that file, but if is an external references, can't be done, so never mind.  Anyway, good luck and if you came up with some change to the code, let me know to see if we could find a new solution.