# CSS animations in html

Tags: html, css, animation

I have animations in html that play when the page loads.

```
<div class="animated bounceInUp zoomin" style="text-align:center;">

<img src="butonwater.png" onclick="" width="200px" height="200px">
</div>
<script>
```

bounceInUp is a CSS animation in my stylesheet. How would I play an animation from the stylesheet onclick?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376815/trigger-animation-on-element-click-in-pure-css

Answer (score 2):

## [Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tqya2JcqiN6bpIjJzf68?p=preview)

There are several ways to restart an animation using `onclick`. Chris Coyier has a [good post](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/) on this.

### Javascript

```
function bounceAgain() {
  var el = document.getElementById("test");
  el.classList.remove('bounceInUp');
  el.offsetWidth = el.offsetWidth;
  el.classList.add('bounceInUp');
}
```

### HTML

Added `bounceAgain()` to `onclick`.

```
<div class="animated bounceInUp zoomin" style="text-align:center;">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/alhBkw5.png" onclick="bounceAgain()" width="300px" height="200px">
</div>
```